# why is internet explorer displaying my javascript pagination backwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Here's a version of the code I'm using, stripped down to just the parts that aren't working. This is all written to generate some basic pagination with jQuery.

In Chrome/Safari/Moz, I generate see spans, 1,2,3,4,...,etc

When I look in IE7/8, I see etc,...,4,3,2,1

The string seems to be concatenating backwards!!

This seems very strange to me, because there's not a whole lot going on in the code here, I can't figure out which bit could be causing problems.

Obviously, the 1,2,3,4,...,etc is what I'm aiming for here, so as well as an explanation of why this is an issue, I'd love it if someone could offer a quick fix.

```
myVar = {
arr:$.makeArray($('.my_li'))
};

var str;
str='';

for (s in myVar.arr){
r=parseInt(s,10)+1;
str+='<span class="my_class">'+r+'</span>';
}

$('#my_other_div').html(str);
```

Comment: because internet exploder is the devil.

Comment: Its possible that the style is causing this to happen. Can you give us the CSS that goes with this?

Comment: IE not displaying correctly? Inconceivable!

Comment: As I stated below, it's appearing backwards in the page source, so it can't be a CSS issue. The problem was that IE looped backwards through the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a `for`...`in` loop on an `Array`. Don't do that, it's only for iterating over the properties of an object being used as a mapping.

JavaScript makes no guarantee you'll get the properties back in array order, and you may also get other non-numeric properties of the Array prototype that you don't want.

Instead, use a plain old `for (var i= 0; i<array.length; i++)` loop. Or, since you're using jQuery, `$.each`.

Comment: knowing that JavaScript doesn't specify the order of properties being returned, I'm inclined to support IE's implementation. Isn't that strange.. Looping down is faster than up, right?

Comment: Marginally. Sometimes. But that's not what IE's really doing — that would be far too easy!

Answer (score 2):

You might find that it's something to do with the CSS class "my_class" or it's parents, rather than anything to do with the javascript.

Have you tried *alert(str)* on the respective browsers?

Comment: it's appearing backwards in the source, it's not a css thing.